# Ipsec connection and nat only one site

Tags: nat, firewall, ipsec

There are two companies and two of them connected to each other with İPsec vpn.  Company A has a server and company B want to reach to company A server. Which company need to configure nat on its firewall? Company A or company B. Or both of them. 
Note: company a server ip address 172.16.16.2/24. Company B is also use same ip block inside its network for another systems.

Comment: There are multiple questions and answers about that here. For example, the one linked in the box above. Please search.

Comment: Hi Serdan, in addition to the link provided by Ron, I would also like to share an article I wrote about this exact same scenario:  https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vpn-overlapping-networks/